# Angular: Using “require” in Directive to require a parent Controller and call parent function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the require attribute in directive to create a link between 2 controllers, everything works great but when I want to invoke a parent function from the child scope I need to use the ugly syntax of $parent.ParentCtl.func() and I would like to know if I can avoid this syntax and invoke the function without explicitly writing the $parent notation.

The child doesn't have isolated scope.

I've look around and didn't find an answer to that question.

At the moment I'm using a factory to bind that functions from parent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The good way

If you're using Angular >=1.5 you can use the `require` syntax in combination with the controllerAs syntax, so instead of using the scope to access the parent, you use a direct reference to the parent which is created by angular, when you explicitly `require` another directive. For example:

```js
angular.module("test", [])
  .directive("foo", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: {},
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: "fooController",
      controller: function() {
        var controller = this;
        controller.something = "Foo Initial Value";
        controller.setSomething = function(something) {
          controller.something = something;
          console.log("Foo Changed:" + something);
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .directive("bar", function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      restrict: "E",
      require: {
        "parent": "^^foo"
      },
      controllerAs: "barController",
      template: "Bar <a href='' ng-click='barController.parent.setSomething(\"from template\")'>Change directly on parent</a>",
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function() {
        var controller = this;
        this.$onInit = function() {
          // We can access the parent after the $onInit.
          console.log(controller.parent.something);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test">
  <foo>
    <bar></bar>
  </foo>
</body>
```

In this example, the `bar` directive requires the `foo` controller, which will get binded to the `parent` property of the `bar` controller.

### The Not-So-Good way

I do not like this way, since the directive's are tied together by the coincidence of they being used in the proper order.

```js
angular.module("test", [])
  .directive("foo", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      scope: true,
      controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.something = "Foo Initial Value";
        $scope.setSomething = function(something) {
          $scope.something = something;
          console.log("Foo Changed:" + something);
        }
      }]
    }
  })
  .directive("bar", function() {
    return {
      scope: true,
      restrict: "E",
      template: "Bar <a href='' ng-click='setSomething(\"from template\")'>Change directly on parent</a> Something: {{something}}"
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="test">
  <foo>
    <bar></bar>
  </foo>
</body>
```

From my experience, I recommend using the ControllerAs syntax.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, but I still need to use the parent notion to call parent function.

I have some function that available in the parent that I would like to expose to child and I would like to use this syntax in template: foo() and that the foo function in parent scope will be called and not using this syntax $parent.Ctrl.foo(), is it possible?

Comment: Hey @johndepp, I've edited my answer to make use of the parent controller directly from the template, although I prefer the original way. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks but you still refer to the parent, I though that since child and parent have the same scope the parent function will be called if not found in the child scope but I guess this is not the case

How would you recommend exposing function in the parent controller to the child controller without duplicating code?

Comment: sorry not same scope but child inherits from parent

Comment: @johndepp, ok so I've added a not so good way which I believe is what you're trying to do, although I do not encourage to do it this way.

Comment: thanks, but now there's no connection between the parent control and child controller like we had before using the require attribute which I prefer.

So I must write the same function in child as in parent and just invoke the parent's function? this sounds odd

Comment: I do not encourage that way because it works by coincidence. You do not need to duplicate any function though.